# Where do questions about computer problems belong?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where can I ask questions about the computer problems I have been facing?

Current problems I am facing with my computers:

- Windows 7 errors
- random "Blue screens of Death"
- computer randomly freezing up
- Xfire challenges

Comment: That would depend on what kind of problem it is. Is it a hardware problem? Network? A misbehaving application?

Comment: updated @Shawn Chin

Answer (score 6):

It all depends on the problem.

Maybe [Super User](http://superuser.com), or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) (if it's about managing computer systems in a professional capacity).

Comment: good point, guess that probably explains my downvote.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your updates, it sounds like http://superuser.com would be your best bet.